# Python: tkinter askyesno method opens an empty window

Tags: python, user-interface, dialog, tkinter

I use this to get yes/no from user but it opens an empty window:

```
from Tkinter import *
from tkMessageBox import *
if askyesno('Verify', 'Really quit?'):
    print "ok"
```

[image]

And this empty window doesnt go away. How can I prevent this?

This won't work:

```
    Tk().withdraw()
    showinfo('OK', 'Select month')
    print "line 677"
    root = Tk()
    root.title("Report month")
    months = ["Jan","Feb","Mar"]
    sel_list = []
    print "line 682"

    def get_sel():
        sel_list.append(Lb1.curselection())
        root.destroy()

    def cancel():
        root.destroy()

    B = Button(root, text ="OK", command = get_sel)
    C = Button(root, text ="Cancel", command = cancel)
    Lb1 = Listbox(root, selectmode=SINGLE)

    for i,j in enumerate(months):
        Lb1.insert(i,j)


    Lb1.pack()
    B.pack()
    C.pack()
    print "line 702"
    root.mainloop()

    for i in sel_list[0]:
        print months[int(i)]
    return months[int(sel_list[0][0])]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create root window explicitly, then withdraw.

```
from Tkinter import *
from tkMessageBox import *
Tk().withdraw()
askyesno('Verify', 'Really quit?')
```

Not beautiful solution, but it works.

---

**UPDATE**

Do not create the second Tk window.

```
from Tkinter import *
from tkMessageBox import *

root = Tk()
root.withdraw()
showinfo('OK', 'Please choose')
root.deiconify()

# Do not create another Tk window. reuse root.

root.title("Report month")
...
```

Comment: But i use other dialogs after this dialog, and for some reason your solution halts my program. any idea why?

Comment: Tk().withdraw()  showinfo('OK', 'Please choose')  root = Tk()  root.title("Report month")  months = ["Jan","Feb","Mar"]     def get_sel():
        sel_list.append(Lb1.curselection())
        root.destroy()
    
    def cancel():
        root.destroy()
    
    B = Button(root, text ="OK", command = get_sel)
    C = Button(root, text ="Cancel", command = cancel)
    Lb1 = Listbox(root, selectmode=SINGLE)
    
    for i,j in enumerate(months):
        Lb1.insert(i,j)
    
    
    Lb1.pack()
    B.pack()
    C.pack()
    print "line 702"
    root.mainloop() return months[int(sel_list[0][0])]

Comment: Could you post that in the body of your question? It's difficult to see what exactly is going on.

Comment: @falsetru nice! what happened?

Comment: @alwbtc, Read Bryan Oakley's explanation.

Answer (score 6):

Tkinter requires that a root window exist before you can create any other widgets, windows or dialogs. If you try to create a dialog before creating a root window, tkinter will automatically create the root window for you.

The solution is to explicitly create a root window, then withdraw it if you don't want it to be visible.

You should always create exactly one instance of `Tk`, and your program should be designed to exit when that window is destroyed.