# tkinter showerror creating blank tk window

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, messagebox, tkmessagebox

I have a program that needs to display graphical error messages to users. It is a tkinter GUI, so I am using `tkinter.messagebox.showerror`

When I call showerror, it shows the error, but also creates a blank "tk" window, the kind created when an instance of the Tk class is called, like `root = Tk()`.

```
from tkinter.messagebox import showerror
showerror(title = "Error", message = "Something bad happened")
```

Produces

[image: Results Of Above Code]

How can I make this blank window not appear?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get rid of Python Tkinter root window?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1406145/how-do-i-get-rid-of-python-tkinter-root-window)

Comment: How are you using this code with the remaining of your code?...is it part of a class?..or what?

Comment: The example given was not in anything. You could say it was in `__main__`. The actual code was inside a function, that's all.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
from Tkinter import *
from tkMessageBox import showerror
Tk().withdraw()
showerror(title = "Error", message = "Something bad happened")
```

Calling `Tk().withdraw()` before showing the error message will hide the root window.

Note: `from tkinter import *` for Python 3.x

Comment: Your import statement might work fine for Python 3.x actually, never used Tkinter on anything higher than 2.5, so if I'm incorrect about the import statements than disregard!

Comment: As long as your imports worked with my solution then all is well, my code just shows what I had to use.

Comment: If I give `Tk().withdraw()`, after my callback method is executed, program doesn't end. Any idea why?

Comment: Isn't there a need to destroy Tk() after `showerror` is closed? If so, the solution by @NagabhushanSN seems more complete.

Answer (score 6):

As explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17932601/3337089) answer, Tkinter requires a root window before we create any more widgets/dialogs. If there is no root window, tkinter creates one. So, to make the blank window disappear, first we need to create a root window ourselves, hide it and destroy it once your dialog action is complete. Sample code below

```
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter.messagebox import showerror

root = Tk()
root.withdraw()
showerror(title = "Error", message = "Something bad happened")
root.destroy()
```

**Note**: This is applicable when you just have to display a dialog and no other window exists.